# InputMismatchException when using Scanner to to read from a file

Tags: java, csv, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I am trying to read from a CSV file using the Scanner but I am getting an InputMismatchException when I try and read the last double and are there is more than one line in my CSV file. I think this is because it is reading \n as part of the double. How do I get it to ignore the line break?

**CSV file**

```
P1,25,30
P2,10,10
```

**Java**

```
public static ArrayList<MarkEntry> readCSV(File file) {
    ArrayList<MarkEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
    try
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(",");
        while (in.hasNext())
        {
            String title = in.next();
            double mark = in.nextDouble();
            double outOf = in.nextDouble(); //Program Crashes here
            entries.add(new MarkEntry(title, mark, outOf));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("File: " + file + " not found");
    }

    return entries;
}
```

Comment: just do String[] input =  in.nexLIne().split(",") and then you will have all your values in each index of the array

Comment: based on the index in the array you can convert to Double or keep as a String

Answer (score 0):

```
    while (in.hasNext())
    {
        String[] inputLine = in.nextLine().split(",");
        //check that the line contains 3 comma seperated values
        if(inputLine.length == 3)
        {
            String title = inputLine[0]; //first on should be P1, p2 etc
            //catch the exception if we are unable to parse the two expected doubls
            try
            {
                double mark = Double.parseDouble(inputLine[1]);
                double outOf = Double.parseDouble(inputLine[2]); //Program Crashes here
                //if we got here then we have valid inputs for adding a MarkEntry
                entries.add(new MarkEntry(title, mark, outOf));
            }catch(NumberFormatException er)
            {
                //print stack trace or something
            }
        }

    }
```